# объявление структуры в php аналогичное js структур

Tags: php, javascript, массивы, struct

Приветствую

Подскажите пожалуйста как в php сформировать структуру, аналогичную JS.

Например:

**JS:**

```
var data = {
    object1: 15,
    object2: {
        element1: 'test',
        element2: 3,
        element3: undefined,
        element4: {
            element5: 11,
        }
    }
};
```

**PHP:**

```
$data = array(
    'object1' => 15,
    'object2' => array(
        'element1' => 'test',
        'element2' => 3,
        'element4' => array(
            'element5' => 11,
        )
    ),
);
```

Так ли это? 
Смущает, что ключ всегда строка, да и вообще выглядит как-то тяжеловато по сравнению с JS.

Comment: В JS ключ тоже строка (в обычных объектах). Да, аналог похож, можно только `array()` на `[]` поменять.

Comment: Вопрос - а зачем вам это надо? И почему вы не пользуетесь `json_encode`?

Comment: u_mulder, у меня есть код на js, мне часть функционала надо на php перенести (чтобы не на клиенте, а на сервере выполнялось), код использует определённую структуру данных

Comment: @Other, не получается array на [] менять - ошибку выдает

Comment: @Zhihar, значит PHP версии малой, оставьте старый синтаксис.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вас есть валидный json, вы всегда можете посмотреть, как определить аналогичную структуру в php, воспользовавшись функцие `var_export`:

```
$js = <<<JSOBJ
{
    "object1": 15,
    "object2": {
        "element1": "test",
        "element2": 3,
        "element3": null,
        "element4": {
            "element5": 11
        }
    }
}
JSOBJ;

$php = json_decode($js, true);

echo var_export($php, true);
```

> ```
> array (
>   'object1' => 15,
>   'object2' => 
>   array (
>     'element1' => 'test',
>     'element2' => 3,
>     'element3' => NULL,
>     'element4' => 
>     array (
>       'element5' => 11,
>     ),
>   ),
> )
> ```

В вопросе у вас не JSON, а js объект. Если в нём только сериализуемые данные(без функций и т.п.), вы можете преобразовать его в валидный json с помощью javascript: `json = JSON.stringify(data);`